# Does receipt of a valid client certificate prove anything?

Tags: .net, certificate, x509certificate

I've read 
[this kb article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/895971) which describes how to send a cert with an http request, and 
[and this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.verify.aspx) describes how the server can validate the cert.  However, am I correct that this does **nothing** to verify that the sender is actually the owner of the cert?  I'm thinking that the establish ownership, a further exchange must take place, where the server would ask the client to encrpyt something using its (the client's) private key, and then the server would decrypt it using the public key provided by the cert. This would be similar to part of the ssl handshake.

What I'm trying to clarify is that simply sending a cert with a request doesn't prove anything about client identity, because it could be spoofed or compromised by a man-in-middle attack. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. I'm far from being a .Net expert but my understanding is that this article  explains how to use a certificate to authenticate the client side in a SSL connection. And as you said, during the SSL Handshake, when the server request a client certificate, the client signs some data and the server performs a validation of that signature in order to prove that the certificate holder owns the private key. Note that the article also contains a section "requirements" specifying that the application must be allowed to access the private key.

Comment: I actually don't read that article as explaining how to authenticate anything.  I take it to be simply how to send a cert.  But you may be right, because simply sending the cert would not require its private key.